# Order results by time added, but rank them by vote count

Tags: php, mysql, ranking

I'm writing a web app where people can add and vote on ideas. When outputting the ideas I want them to be ordered by their total vote count or time added, but always have a rank based on the vote count.

This is what I have now:

```
function get_ideas($status, $sortby, $count, $page){
    $offset = ($page - 1) * $count;
    $dbh = db_connect();
    if($sortby === 'popular'){
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("
            SELECT i.idea_id, i.idea_datetime, i.user_id, i.idea_title, i.idea_text, 
            i.idea_vote_count, u.user_name, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank 
            FROM ideas i 
            JOIN (SELECT @curRank := :rankoffset) AS q
            JOIN users u ON i.user_id = u.user_id
            WHERE idea_status = :idea_status 
            ORDER BY idea_vote_count DESC 
            LIMIT :count 
            OFFSET :offset;");
    } else {
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("HOW DO I DO THIS???");
    }
    $stmt->bindParam(':idea_status', $status, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':rankoffset', $offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':count', $count, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':offset', $offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $stmt = NULL;
    $dbh = NULL;
    return $result;
}
```

The code in the "if" block works as intended - it returns an array ordered by "idea_vote_count" with correct ranks.

However, I have no idea what the second statement should be. Ordering by time added would be achieved easily enough by just changing "idea_vote_count" in the "ORDER BY" clause to "idea_id". How do I get the ranks, though? I couldn't think of nor find a solution which didn't involve storing the ranks in the table itself.

Hopefully I've explained my problem clearly, but just in case:

How do I get a table like this:

```
idea_id | idea_vote_count
      1 |              20
      2 |              40
      3 |              30
      4 |               5
```

To produce output like this:

```
rank | idea_id | idea_vote_count
   4 |       4 |               5
   2 |       3 |              30
   1 |       2 |              40
   3 |       1 |              20
```

Also, I'm kind of new to PHP and MySQL, so if you spot any other problems, please, point them out.

I look forward to your advice. Thanks :)

EDIT: For Strawberry:

My ideas table:

```
CREATE TABLE `ideas`(
`idea_id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`idea_datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
`user_id` int NOT NULL,
`idea_title` varchar(48) NOT NULL,
`idea_text` text NOT NULL,
`idea_vote_count` int NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
`idea_status` varchar(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'active',
PRIMARY KEY(`idea_id`),
FOREIGN KEY(`user_id`) REFERENCES users(`user_id`)) 
ENGINE=INNODB;
```

The sample ideas have been generated by following script. I have then manually changed the `idea_vote_count` of row 100 to 5.

```
$i = 1;
set_time_limit(150);
while (i<101) {
    $datetime = date('Y-m-d h:m:s');
    $dbh->exec(INSERT INTO `ideas` (`idea_datetime`, `user_id`, `idea_title`, `idea_text`, `idea_vote_count`, `idea_status`) 
    VALUES ('{$datetime}', $i, 'Title{$i}', 'Text{$i}', $i, 'active');
    $i++
    sleep(1);
}
```

This is what I ended up with after incorporating Strawberry's SQL into my function:

```
function get_ideas($status, $sortby, $count, $page){
    $offset = ($page - 1) * $count;
    $dbh = db_connect();
    if($sortby === 'popular'){
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("
        SELECT i.idea_id, i.idea_datetime, i.user_id, i.idea_title, i.idea_text, i.idea_vote_count, u.user_name, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank 
        FROM ideas i 
        JOIN (SELECT @curRank := :rankoffset) AS q
        JOIN users u 
        ON i.user_id = u.user_id
        WHERE idea_status = :idea_status 
        ORDER BY idea_vote_count DESC 
        LIMIT :count 
        OFFSET :offset;");
    } else {
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("
        SELECT n.*
        FROM (
            SELECT i.idea_id, i.idea_datetime, i.user_id, i.idea_title, i.idea_text, i.idea_vote_count, u.user_name, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank 
            FROM ideas i 
            JOIN (SELECT @curRank := :rankoffset) AS q
            JOIN users u 
            ON i.user_id = u.user_id
            WHERE idea_status = :idea_status 
            ORDER BY idea_vote_count DESC 
            LIMIT :count 
            OFFSET :offset) n
        ORDER BY idea_id DESC;");
    }
    $stmt->bindParam(':idea_status', $status, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':rankoffset', $offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':count', $count, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':offset', $offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $stmt = NULL;
    $dbh = NULL;
    return $result;
}
```

As you can see, the function takes $count and $page as arguments (usually these have value of $_REQUEST['count/page']) and calculates the offset and limit based on them. This is very important, because I don't want to show all the ideas to users at the same time, I want to split them into several pages. However, this messes with the select/ranking SQL in the following way:

When $page = 1 and $count = 100 you get LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0 and the script works as intended - it shows the most recent row (row 100) as the first one ranked 96 (only rows 1, 2, 3, 4 have lower vote count), followed by the other recent rows ranked 1, 2, 3 and so on.

However, when $page = 1 and $count = 10 you get LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0 and the script outputs row 99 first, because it's the highest rated one, but not the most recent. Row 100 becomes the first result in the result set when $page = 10 (the lowest rated and OLDEST rows, despite the fact that row 100 is the most recent).

I could technically select the entire table and then handle the pagination in PHP, but I fear what the performance impact would be.

EDIT2: I have moved OFFSET and LIMIT into the outer SELECT and now everything works as it's supposed to. The side effect of this is, that the inner SELECT selects the entire table, but hopefully it won't grow too big for the server to handle. This is the solution I'm sticking with for the time being. It's based on Strawberry's SQL, so I'll mark that as the answer. Thanks, Strawberry :)

Comment: You can sort an array any way you like

Comment: I know, but I couldn't figure out how to order them by time while calculating the same rank as if they were ordered by their vote count.

Comment: The performance impact on a dataset as tiny as this will be negligible. If you output the dataset to json, you wouldn't even need php. Javascript could handle the pagination and ordering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one idea, using purely MySQL, but it's probably better just to return the data set with the ranks and then do any further ordering in the application code...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(idea_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,idea_vote_count INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1 ,20),
(2 ,40),
(3 ,30),
(4 ,5);

SELECT n.* 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT x.*
            , @i:=@i+1 rank 
         FROM my_table x
            , (SELECT @i:=0) vars 
        ORDER 
           BY idea_vote_count DESC
     ) n 
 ORDER 
    BY idea_id DESC;
+---------+-----------------+------+
| idea_id | idea_vote_count | rank |
+---------+-----------------+------+
|       4 |               5 |    4 |
|       3 |              30 |    2 |
|       2 |              40 |    1 |
|       1 |              20 |    3 |
+---------+-----------------+------+
```

Comment: This works when selecting all the rows in a table, but not when selecting just a subset. My testing table actually has about 100 rows. I have given the last row a vote count of 5. When $page = 1 and $count = 100, it returns everything correctly (starts with idea_id 100 ranked 96). However, when $page = 1 and $count = 10 it starts with row 99.

Comment: I don't follow. This returns the the sample data set in the required way. It even provides proper DDLs.

Comment: SELECT n.*
FROM (
   SELECT *columns*, &#64;curRank := &#64;curRank + 1 AS rank
      FROM ideas i 
      JOIN (SELECT &#64;curRank := :rankoffset) AS q
      JOIN users u 
      ON i.user_id = u.user_id
      WHERE idea_status = :idea_status 
      ORDER BY idea_vote_count DESC 
      LIMIT :count 
      OFFSET :offset) n
ORDER BY idea_id DESC;"

This is what I ended up with when I adapted your SQL to the rest of my function (most notably the pagination). My actual testing table has 100 rows, each has a vote count 1 higher than the previous, except row 100 which is set to 5. (Continues below)

Comment: Your SQL works perfectly when the pagination is taken out of the picture by setting $page = 1 and $count = 100 (resulting in LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0). This encompasses the entire table and returns row 100 (the most recent one) ranked 96 (only rows 1-4 have fewer votes) as the first one.

However, $page = 1 and $count = 10 (LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0) selects only the 10 highest rated rows (99-90) despite the fact that row 100 is more recent. Row 100 reappears when $page = 10.

Comment: Nope, you've lost me - but it sounds like you've solved your problem anyway.

Comment: I apologize for my terrible explaining skills. They say 1 picture is worth 1000 words, so here we go. Here's a very early version of the site with the function above in use.
Count 100: https://scontent-vie.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xap1/t31.0-8/11145895_10202831390466227_4490979386978486477_o.jpg
Count 10: https://scontent-vie.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpa1/t31.0-8/11169777_10202831390106218_8051773111060927344_o.jpg

Comment: No pictures thanks. Just proper DDLs, with enough INSERTs to be representative AND the desired result

Comment: I've updated the main question, hopefully it'll now be clear what issue I'm running into.